# How to use Order By on with or wherehas hasone relationship

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am trying to order it by curriculum but it didn't work. I also tried many ways but still can't find the right answer.

**my query:**

```
Students::with('StudentUser','Curriculum','Program','YearLevel','Semester')->get()
```

**my model:**

```
public function StudentUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}

public function Curriculum()
{
    return $this->HasOne('App\Curriculum', 'id','curriculum_id');
}

public function Program()
{
    return $this->HasOne('App\Program', 'id','program_id');
}

public function YearLevel()
{
    return $this->HasOne('App\YearLevel', 'id','year_level_id');
}

public function Semester()
{
    return $this->HasOne('App\Semester', 'id','semester_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
Students::with('StudentUser','Curriculum','Program','YearLevel','Semester')
          ->join('Curriculum', 'students.id', '=', 'Curriculum.curriculum_id')
          ->orderBy('curriculum.curriculum_id')
          ->get()
```

Comment: actually, I'd already try this one but I want to try not using join. because the result for the relation curriculum will be redundant

Comment: you can remove repetitve data from collection using `unique()`,  `$collection->unique();`, or use `distinct()` to get distinct values for a column

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap the results into a collection and order that.i.e.

```
$orderedStudents = new Collection(
 Students::with('StudentUser','Curriculum','Program','YearLevel','Semester')->get()
)->sortBy('Curriculum');
```

// Please keep in mind that ascending is default, if you need Descending order, use `sortByDesc()`

Comment: because what returned is already a collection, you can directly use sortBy in the instance directly

Comment: also change curriculum by the column name, eg if $orderedStudents has curriculum with column x then use sortBy(curriculum.x)